# selecionar os 2 primeiros caracteres no WHERE do db

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, select

No banco de dados tenho a tabela Tcodigos, no qual fornece um lista de codigos para consulta em outra tela, preciso que no where do select no banco de dados, selecione e compare apenas os 2 primeiros caracteres do cod no banco de dados.

```
public function indexjson($cod = '')
{
    $parCOD = substr($cod, 0, 2); // Retorna os 2 primeiros números da variável(preciso fazer o mesmo no tcodigos.cod.
    if ($parCOD == '') {
        $codigos = Tcodigos::all(['id', 'cod', 'descricao']);
    } else {
        $codigos = DB::table('Tcodigos')
        ->select('tcodigos.id', 'tcodigos.cod', 'tcodigos.descricao')
        ->where("tcodigos.cod", "=", $parCOD) // Preciso que no where pegue apenas os 2 primeiros caracteres do tcodigos.cod
        ->get();
    }
    return $codigos->toJson();
}
```

Edit:
Adicionei a o substr com o db::raw, ele nao esta dando erro, porem nao esta retornando nenhum valor dentro do array.

```
public function indexjson($cod = '')
{
    $parCOD = substr($cod, 0, 2); // Retorna os 2 primeiros números da variável(preciso fazer o mesmo no tcodigos.cod.
    if ($parCOD == '') {
        $codigos = Tcodigos::all(['id', 'cod', 'descricao']);
    } else {
        $codigos = DB::table('Tcodigos')
        ->select('tcodigos.id', 'tcodigos.cod', 'tcodigos.descricao')
        ->where(DB::raw("substr(tcodigos.cod, 0, 2)"), '=', substr($parCOD, 0, 2)) // Preciso que no where pegue apenas os 2 primeiros caracteres do tcodigos.cod
        ->get();
    }
    return $codigos->toJson();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Esse tipo de processamento é mais interessante fazer via aplicação, não por banco. Mas se realmente quer fazer via banco, acredito que algo como isso resolva:

```php
$codigos = DB::table('Tcodigos')
        ->select('tcodigos.id', 'tcodigos.cod', 'tcodigos.descricao')
        ->where(DB::raw('tcodigos.cod == SUBSTRING(?, 1, 2)'))
        ->setBindings([$parCOD])
        ->get();
```

A ideia é usar o método do banco SUBSTRING para cortar suas string no banco (importante verificar se o seu tipo de banco tem essa função. SQLServer e Postgres tem) E por fim, fazer o bind do valor em ? com o seu $parCOD.

EDIT:
Outra forma de fazer isso, pode ser usando o `whereRaw`, por exemplo:
`->whereRaw('tcodigos.cod == SUBSTRING(?, 1, 2)', [$parCOD])`
E nesse caso, vc nao precisaria colocar o `setBindings` pois o valor já foi bindado no próprio whereRaw

EDIT 2:
Para MySQL você tem o operador `LIKE` ele ajuda em alguns casos. E nesse caso, vc pode trocar aquele `DB::raw` e o `setBindings` por um where simples que use esse operador, por exemplo:

`->where('tcodigos.cod', 'like', $parCOD . '%')`
Nesse caso, vc estará filtrando por todos os códigos que comecem com o valor contido na variavel $parCOD e o restante da string pode ser qualquer valor. Mais exemplos do operador LIKE em: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Ainda nao consegui, esta dando erro

Comment: @IgorTomás qual o banco que vc está usando?

Comment: Uso o banco mysql.

Comment: @IgorTomás Da uma olhada no meu EDIT 2. Ve se isso resolve o seu problema